# How do I use require() with local, file-based dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dependencies, npm-install

I am working with a Node.js application. My `package.json` has a handful of file-based dependencies.

**package.json**

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        ...
        "foo": "file:local-dependencies/foo"
        ...
     }
}
```

I've done a full `npm install` at my project's root, and everything looks great. Now, in a file in my project, I'd like to use `foo`:

**handlers/bar.js**

```
const Foo = require('foo');
```

However, when I attempt to start my app, I get the error below, with a stack trace that leads me to that `require` statement.

`Error: Cannot find module 'foo'`

For reference, here's some of what is inside `local-dependencies/foo`:

**local-dependencies/foo/index.js**

```
(function() {
    const blah = exports;
    // add properties and functions to blah
})();
```

I'm new to Node.js, so I haven't explored exactly what the `exports` keyword here does, but should that be enough to export the module so it can be required?

The only other thing worth noting is that I've obviously simplified some things here. In actuality, the `foo` directory has a git hash after it in the name, so it looks more like `local-dependencies/foo-59775e6b6dd01ceb34342da93abb60ee43b71eb8`. Does the directory have to be strictly named `foo`?

Comment: Is your file module exporting something?

Comment: I'm new to Node.js, so I'm not entirely sure. Let me add a little more information to the question that hopefully will answer your question.

Comment: why don't you put the file inside project structure and require it's relative path? require('./file/relative/path/file.js')

Comment: I think that's the best eventuality. The local dependency with the `file:` syntax is a half measure on the way there. We were previously depending on a git repo using the syntax `git://`, but the repo's permissions changed on us, so we're having to bring the dependency in-house. I agree, we should end up just having it inside project structure.